# Error when passing an object that implements interface X to an interface Y that inherits from interface X. in C#

Tags: c#

Currently when passing an object that implements interface X to an interface Y that inherits from interface X I am getting the following error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'InterfaceTestApp.Repositories.IUserModel' to
>   'InterfaceTestApp.Lib.IUserModel'. An explicit conversion exists (are
>   you missing a cast?)

This is my test setup:

**Repository**

```
namespace InterfaceTestApp.Repositories
{
    public class UserTestRepo
    {
        public IUserModel GetUser() => new UserModel() { Id = 1, Name = "Test" };
    }
}

namespace InterfaceTestApp.Repositories
{
    public interface IUserModel
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserModel : IUserModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Library**

```
namespace InterfaceTestApp.Lib
{
    interface IUserModelLib : Repositories.IUserModel { }
}

namespace InterfaceTestApp.Lib
{
    class Authentication
    {
        public IUserModelLib AuthenticateUser() => new Repositories.UserTestRepo().GetUser();
    }
}
```

Basically what I am trying to do here is to avoid exposing any portions of the Repo project to any application using the Lib project. As you can see, the IUserModelLib is just a pass through interface. It inherits everything from the IUserModel in the repo project.

There should be a way to do this without having to do some kind of manual casting. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `IUserModelLib` can do anything that `IUserModel` can do, but not vice versa. You try to return `IUserModel` from `IUserModelLib AuthenticateUser()` method, but `IUserModel` doesn't have any functionality that `IUserModelLib` may have inside it's own declaration, hence error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You confused the order / direction of inheritance here.

- `Lib.IUserModelLib` implements `Repositories.IUserModel`
- `UserModel` implements `Repositories.IUserModel`

Just because they share a common interface doesn't mean `UserModel` can be assignet to `Lib.IUserModelLib`.

- `Repositories.UserTestRepo().GetUser()` returns a `Repositories.IUserModel`
- Therefore `AuthenticateUser()` needs to return a `Repositories.IUserModel` instead of a `Lib.IUserModelLib`

> Basically what I am trying to do here is to avoid exposing any portions of the Repo project to any application using the Lib project. As you can see, the IUserModelLib is just a pass through interface. It inherits everything from the IUserModel in the repo project.

In that case you need to wrap the `UserModel` class, not the `IUserModel` interface, set the class to `internal` instead of `public` and define your [friend-assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt632254.aspx). That way you can use `UserModel` in your Lib project without exposing it to any project using the Lib.

Comment: Thank for the confirmation! Greatly appreciated. ;0)